# GCC can't locate headers even when the search directory is correct

Tags: c, gcc, include

Once again, GCC is making me feel like an idiot for having trouble with the simplest things. I've included a header:

```
#include "PDL.h"
```

Then, I try to compile:

```
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc -I/cygdrive/c/PalmPDK/include -I../lua-5.1.4/lua-webos/include -O2 -Wall -shared -nostdlib -mcpu=arm1136jf-s -mfpu=vfp -mfloat-abi=softfp -lpdl
```

But it says:

> PDL.h: no such file or directory

I can change into the include directory I specified above and see PDL.h is there, but GCC just doesn't see it.

Comment: Did you double check case of file and directory names?  (gcc being developed mainly on Unix with case sensitive files and you are on windows with case insensitive one,  there may be something)

Comment: Yeah, casing is exactly the same.

Comment: Try --verbose option of gcc which should give you the path searched.

Comment: Can you show us the other gcc options you are using?  One of them may perhaps be overriding the `-I` statement shown.

Comment: Using `--verbose` gave me `ignoring nonexistent directory /cygdrive/c/PalmPDK/include`. But if I copy and paste that path directly as an argument to `cd`, it gives me no error and changes into that directory. I'll edit my question with the other options, as well.

Comment: Are you running gcc from the Cyqwin shell or from the DOS shell?

Comment: I'm running it from the Cygwin shell.

Comment: Where does your gcc comes from?  /cygdrive is something specific to cygwin, so if gcc isn't compiled in a cygwin environment, it won't search it.  Perhaps try using C:/PalmPDK/include

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem. I'm not familiar with how Cygwin works, so I thought a Makefile run in a Cygwin shell would use the same paths as the shell, but it actually uses Windows paths. Just a case of me not providing you all with enough info (the fact I was using a Makefile). Sorry. If you want to post that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @David Brown- You can use Cygwin-style paths in your makefiles, you just have to use the appropriate `SHELL`.  See the update to my answer for details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

/cygdrive is something specific to cygwin, so if gcc isn't compiled to use the cygwin unix emulation layer, it won't search it. Try using `-IC:/PalmPDK/include`.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>The `#include "file.h"` syntax looks in the current directory, then in the default include directories for the header file.  Instead, use the `#include <file.h>` syntax in order to pick up the directories specified on the command-line.</strike>

If you want to use the quoted-filename syntax, use the syntax `-iquoteFOLDER_PATH` to [point to your include directory on the command-line](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.0/gcc/Directory-Options.html#Directory-Options).

**Edit:** Given your comment about the makefile, make sure that you have set (and `export`) the `SHELL` variable in your makefile.  When running Cygwin under Windows, you can set it to cmd.exe or to Cygwin bash (works best if you include the full path to each).  Whichever environment you list in your `SHELL` variable will be used to execute the commands in the makefile.  You can use whatever shell you wish, just make sure to specify one or the other so you can be sure that you are using the correct path style for the given shell.  For good measure, also set (and `export`) the `MAKESHELL` variable using the same value.

Comment: I tried using brackets, but it didn't change the output. I also have other search directories specified with `-I` whose headers are included with quotes and they work just fine. This only happens with headers in `/cygdrive/c/PalmPDK/include`. Which would lead me to believe it's a typo or something, but I can change to that directory and see PDL.h exists.

Comment: "file.h" must use the <file.h> algorithm if the file isn't found before.

Comment: gcc searches for "..." includes in -I directories just fine. Even with -I- all -I options will be searched for local includes. Are you talking about something weird and specific to this cross compiler?

Comment: @Owen- Re-reading the gcc docs I see that you are correct.  I think I am using a non-conforming gcc implementation (which would explain a couple of other things...).  I should fix that.

Answer (score 0):

If you have spaces in the path you'll need to escape them or surround the path with double quotes.

Comment: There are no spaces in the path (which I included in my question).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're on a Linux box, or some flavor of Unix:

```
ls -l /
ls -l /cygdrive
ls -l /cygdrive/c
ls -l /cygdrive/c/PalmPDK
ls -l /cygdrive/c/PalmPDK/include
```

You will probably find your answer in the results of one of the commands listed above.

Comment: All of those commands succeeded and the last one displayed PDL.h. Like I said, a typo would make sense, but I've checked and rechecked.